# Gulp Critical CSS and Twig Files

Tags: css, gulp, twig, timber

I'm trying to use this for applying critical css into my twig files.

I've had this working perfectly before but i've updated to gulp 4 and restructured my gulp file(s). i'm trying to also include multiple dimensions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
                    var critical = require( 'critical' ).stream;

            function critical() {
                return critical( plugins.path.join( project.paths.base ) )
                    .pipe( critical.generate({ inline: true, base: project.paths.views, dest: plugins.path.join( project.paths.views, 'html-header.twig' ), src: plugins.path.join( project.paths.build, 'css/style.min.css' ),
                     dimensions: [{
                            height: 200,
                            width: 500
                        }, {
                            height: 900,
                            width: 1200
                        }] }) )
                    .pipe( gulp.dest( project.paths.views ) );
            }

            gulp.task( 'critical-css', critical );
```

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
    'use strict';
    /**
     * Project Setup
     *
     * Setting up variables for project name and directories
     */


     /******************************************************************************
      | >   PLUGINS
      ******************************************************************************/
    global.gulp = require('gulp');
    var HubRegistry = require('gulp-hub');
    var hub = new HubRegistry(['tasks/{,**/}*.js']);

    global.plugins = {
        path: require('path'),
        rename: require('gulp-rename'),
        changed: require('gulp-changed'),
        concat: require('gulp-concat'),
        browserSync: require('browser-sync'),
        sourcemaps: require('gulp-sourcemaps')
    };

    /******************************************************************************
     | >   PROJECT VARIABLES
     ******************************************************************************/

    global.project = {
        name:       'base',
        url:        'localhost:8888/base/',
        phpSource:  ['**/*.php', 'page-templates/**/*.php', '!library/**/*', '!wpcs/**/*', '!node_modules/**/*', '!vendor/**/*', '!assets/bower_components/**/*', '!**/*-min.css', '!assets/js/vendor/*', '!assets/css/*', '!**/*-min.js', '!assets/js/production.js'],

        paths: {
            base: __dirname,
            build: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'build' ),
            src: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'src' ),
            vendors: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'vendor' ),
            tasks: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'tasks' ),
            views: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'views' ),
            assets: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'assets' ),

            assets: {
                sass: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'src/sass' ),
                images: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'assets/img' ),
                js: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'assets/js' ),
                css: plugins.path.join( __dirname, 'assets/css' )
            }
        }
    };

    gulp.registry(hub);

    gulp.task('images', gulp.series('image-fallback', 'image-optimise', 'image-responsive'));
```

The critical css needs to go into html-header.twig

```
    <!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js ie ie6 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" {{site.language_attributes}}> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie ie7 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" {{site.language_attributes}}> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie ie8 lt-ie9" {{site.language_attributes}}> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" {{site.language_attributes}}> <!--<![endif]-->
    <html id="csstyle">
    <head>
        <meta charset="{{site.charset}}" />
            <title>
                {% if wp_title %}
                    {{ wp_title }} - {{ site.name }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ site.name }}
                {% endif %}
            </title>
        <meta name="description" content="{{site.description}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.theme.link}}/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {{function('wp_head')}}
```

I can't post images because of my small reputation.

Here is my file structure:

[File Structure](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4720782/13248281/564c2c64-da15-11e5-8dc8-a9553d690c9c.png)

When I run gulp critical-css in the terminal i get this error

[10:47:17] The following tasks did not complete: critical-css

[10:47:17] Did you forget to signal async completion?

I'm using version 0.7.1 of [Critical](https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical)

Thanks Jake.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first four lines:

```
var critical = require( 'critical' ).stream;

function critical() {
  return critical( plugins.path.join( project.paths.base ) )
    .pipe( critical.generate(
```

- You define a `function` and a `var` both named `critical`. Name you function `criticalCss` or anything else.
- You're using `path.join` with a single argument. Probably missing something here.
- `critical.stream` can only take an options object, not a path. You want `return gulp.src` instead of `return critical`.
- `critical.generate` doesn't return a `stream.Transform`, so you can't pass it to `stream.pipe()`. You want `critical({})` like in [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical#gulp).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, i've now changed it to this.

                var critical = require( 'critical' ).stream;

                function critical() {
                    return gulp.src( plugins.path.join( project.paths.views, 'html-header.twig' ) )
                        .pipe( critical({ base: project.paths.views, inline: true, css: [ plugins.path.join( project.paths.build, 'css/style.min.css' ) ] } ) )
                        .pipe( gulp.dest( project.paths.views ) );
                };

Comment: When i run it in terminal i get this. 

AssertionError: Forward referenced task 'critical-css' not defined before use
    at tempTask (/Users/beast/Documents/code/base/wp-content/themes/base-child/node_modules/undertaker-forward-reference/index.js:11:5)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:300:12)
    at asyncRunner (/Users/beast/Documents/code/base/wp-content/themes/base-child/node_modules/async-done/index.js:36:18)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:453:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:382:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)

Comment: extending...

    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3